# Was Jesus' cry in Mark 15:34-36 misunderstood for vinegar?

Tags: jesus, mark, passion

We read in Mark 25:34-36 how Jesus calls out "Eli, Eli..." before his death on the cross. The words are misinterpreted by some who say that he is calling Elijah. One person, however, runs and returns with gall-mixed vinegar. There is a view that in Aramaic language the words 'hil' and 'hila' stand for vinegar. So, he might have thought that Jesus was asking for the pain-killer vinegar, on account of which he ran for it.

Are there any references to the interpretation of the words "Eli, Eli..." Jesus uttered on the cross, vis-a-vis the vinegar that was brought to him in a hurry?

Comment: Mark informs us of the actual wording (Aramaic) 'Eloi, Eloi' which Jesus spoke. Matthew gives the original Hebrew, 'Eli, Eli' ; from Psalm 22. The confusion of the hearer may well be due to the anguish of the speaker and, thus, distortion in the ears of the hearer.  'Vinegar' in Hebrew is _chomets_ [see Strong 558](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2558.htm) so I cannot see that the Aramaic can be 'hil' or 'hila'.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are wondering whether "Eli" = "chela".

It's difficult to see how that would be sustainable for the following reasons:

1. In ur Greek NT we have preserved for us what Jesus said: “ἐλωῒ ἐλωΐ, λαμὰ σαβαχθανεί;” (Μάρκον 15·34 THGNT-T) "My God, my God, why have you abandoned me?" The rendering in Mark preserves for us the Aramaic wording (אֱלָהִי)  But the difficulty is that it's also recorded for us in Matthew:  “ἠλεὶ ἠλεί, λεμὰ σαβαχθανεί” (Μαθθαῖον 27·46 THGNT-T). Matthew preserves for us the Hebrew wording (ἠλεί = אֵלִי). There is debate which *dialect* Jesus spoke. He may have spoken Aramaic (as most did at the time). He may, however, have spoken direct Hebrew to show a more direct fulfillment of the OT prophecy.  So, already, it's difficult to figure out the precise, original wording.
2. In Greek we can perhaps conclude that there was a switch between "ἐλωῒ" and "Ἠλίαν" ("my God" and "Elijah"). But it's a stretch to conclude that אֵלִי/אֱלָהִי" would be heard as "אֵ֣לִיָּ֔הוּ". The hearers would have to assume two extra syllables.
3. The third detail you mention almost makes sense linguistically.  “ἠλεί” (Μαθθαῖον 27·46 THGNT-T) could (linguistically) sound like "ܚܰܠܳܐ". For Greek has no way of rendering the gutturals. So, the possessive on the word, "chali" would sound like "Eli."  The difficulty is that no one I've ever read has made a case for that. The other difficulty is contextual. Why would he be saying, "My vinegar, my vinegar, why have you forsaken me?"

I hope this is enough to walk you through the difficulties of that sort of interpretation.

Comment: Very good answer.  Further, the other gospels also record his declaration, "I thirst".

Comment: Thanks, Epimanes. The question is not how Jesus pronounced Eli Eli, but how the people around heard him.. Consider that the right pronunciation of Elijah ( which in fact is the English adaptation,) is Eliyah ( e as in earnest ) . Those who interpreted as such, could be justified to an extend because Jesus  was literally finding it hard to breathe. It is something else that a simple soldier or a civilian heard something else and interpreted it in his own way. What is notable here is that he ran to collect the vinegar. By the way, if you are good at Syriac, what is the word for vinegar ?

Comment: You might also mention that "*My God, My God, why has thou forsaken me?*" is a direct quotation from Psalms 22:1. It's very unlikely Jesus would choose this moment to make a pun.

Comment: I suppose the argument in favor of vinegar might include the idea that "why have you forsaken me" wasn't clearly articulated.

Comment: That is right , Dan Fefferman. But, this is not the first instance of mishearing by the people. See Jn 12:29 where the words of God the Father are misunderstood as ' thunder'.

Comment: Let us also keep in mind that three main languages namely, Hebrew, Aramaic and Greek were in use in the locality where Jesus lived. All had certain similarities and differences , which no one would be a master of. There must have been someone on permanent duty on Calvary to serve the painkiller vinegar to the convicts. The person on duty on the day of Jesus' crucifixion may have only heard " Eli, eli..." ...before running to the jar which contained vinegar.